# Can optimism "boost" the immune system

Tags: medical-science, immune-system

[image]

Can your attitude (a positive outlook,  optimism, "fighting spirit" etc, or the converse) influence how well your immune system works? Most research that confirm mood correlating with immune system [seem to show it for stress](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7413/does-stress-weaken-ones-immune-system), which is a physiological change in you body, something completely different.

But being optimistic, in itself, could that possibly influence you immune system?

Example of the claim: [LiveScience.com: Optimism Boosts Immune System](http://www.livescience.com/8158-optimism-boosts-immune-system.html). The usage of "boost" in combination with "immune system" is enough to raise some flags.

Comment: Related question: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/42/is-it-possible-to-boost-your-immune-system

Comment: An interesting piece I read some time ago... kind of related http://struckbyenlightning.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/positive-thinking/

Comment: Seems highly related to the placebo effect.

Comment: I don't have the book on me ATM but this is asserted in the book Learned Optimism ( http://amzn.to/UevEr6 ) by Martin Seligman, PhD. The book references several studies done to prove this point. I know it's not enough for a complete answer (thus the comment) but it's worth checking out!

Comment: We have established earlier that [stress weakens the immune system](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7413/does-stress-weaken-ones-immune-system). You could argue that negativity leads to stress, or that good thoughts reduce stress, which can be seen as "boosting" the immune system - even if from a weakened state back to something more normal. Sorry, no sources to cite on this reasoning.

Comment: You can't say that stress is distinct from your state of mind simply by saying that stress is physiological and thereby 'different'.  Your emotional state clearly has physical effects on your body, as anybody who regularly checks pulse and blood pressure can testify.  Now, whether optimism affects your immune system, I can't say and don't know of any studies... I expect the effect would be minimal.  I'm just pointing out that you shouldn't fall victim to the assumption that there's a clear mind/body dichotomy.

Comment: @kbelder: True that. When I say "completely different" I'm just making a distinction akin to "if I hurt my knee, I feel pain". Just because I feel optimistic about my injury doesn't mean the bleeding will stop.

Comment: yes obviously, it brings a lot changes to my life.

Comment: Does the placebo effect count as proof of this?

Answer (score 2):

[Psychoneuroimmunology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychoneuroimmunology) is the research field relevant for your question, where [research indicates that the feeling of optimism is good for work success, financial success, and good health](http://www.therapyhub.com/articles/therapy-tips/five-ways-increase-optimism).

[Optimism and the Immune System](https://joshuawiley.com/pres/optimism_immune.html#title-slide) give you an overview of the subject.

[Optimism and immunity: Do positive thoughts always lead to positive effects?](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0889159104001205?np=y) says that "empirical evidence suggests that [the effects of dispositional optimism] is more likely to be a consequence of optimists’ greater engagement during difficult stressors".

Comment: Can you quote the relevant parts from the articles? That and complete you answer it's unfinished as it is now. Avoid saying "You may also want to read" in an answer, or "You should easily find..". An answer should be as complete as possible!